# optimize get or create pattern in hibernate

Tags: performance, hibernate

I am saving entries in table only if they already exist:

```
public static Email getOrCreate(Session sess, String address) {
    if (address==null) return null;
    List l = sess.createQuery("SELECT email FROM Email email WHERE email.address=:address").setString("address", address).list();
    if (l.size() > 0)
        return (Email) l.get(0);
    Email email = new Email(address);
    sess.save(email);
    return email;
}
```

I am not satisfied with the speed of this procedure. It takes me about 5 mins to save 5000 complicated records and 50% of time is occupied by this function. My hibernate cache setting is: 
            cfg.setProperty("hibernate.cache.provider_class", "org.hibernate.cache.EhCacheProvider");

Of course I could create static map and sync it with database sometimes, but it looks a bit ugly. Can hibernate do something like this? Thanx.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it in batch:

```
Set<String> addresses = ...;
List<String> existingAddresses = 
    session.createQuery("select email.address from Email email where email.address in :addresses")
           .setParameterList("addresses", addresses)
           .list();
addresses.removeAll(existingAddresses);
for (String address : addresses) {
    session.save(new Email(address));
}
```

Make sure, though, that your database allows 5000 elements in an `IN` clause. Oracle, for example, limits them to 1000. But you could still only execute 5 request instead of 5000.

That said, 5 minutes to do that looks like a whole lot to me. Do you have a database index defined on email.address?

Comment: If you're able to iterate and call this method 5000 times, then you should be able to iterate and collect the 5000 addresses into a set, shouldn't you?

Comment: I am importing mail messages. Emails come from different places of app. So it is possible to collect all of them, but this would look very ugly. May be it is possible to implement this deferred way? I.e. subclassed Email is created, which with some other Emails?

Comment: I tried others methods to speed up this process and had to implement your solution. So, I'll accept it. Thanx...